# What's faster? "explode" or another column?

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I have a situation where I need to have multiple values stored in my database but they are approx. same type so now I don't know is it faster to store those values as a **String** in **VARCHAR** field in MySQL separated with **commas**

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

and then explode them every them I need them

```
$values = explode(",", $stringFromDatabase);
```

where *$stringFromDatabase* is **String** from **mysql_query** + **mysql_fetch_array** and get them one by one with **$values[0]**, **$values[1]** and so on

**OR**

Add another columns for every variable (max. 7 rows) and then call the database for specific row and just get them individually by columns with standard **mysql_query** + **mysql_fetch_array** procedure?

So, one column concatenated with commmas or multiple columns? Important to notice, I always need them all (one by one ofcourse) and sorting is not important - so I think that the **first option** - is the **better**, faster one?

Comment: I also have almost similar kind of question ,

so thought of posting here only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its better to have multiple columns. It part of database normalization not to have multivalued columns.

In your case - what if you needed to select the "`3`" on from the multivalued `1,2,3,4,5`? It would be quite challenging. But with multiple columns I can easily do `SELECT * FROM Table Where Column3 = 3`.

Comment: But he says that he will always need every value, one by one.

Comment: Yes but if he's trying to query the value that meets a condition.

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb with databases is that columns should be atomic.  In other words, they should represent one piece of information and only one.  Cramming a CSV list into a column breaks this principle and can make life harder for you in the long run, especially when it comes to doing analytics on the data you have stored.  I'd suggest that having one column per value would be the best bet.

Comment: Add to that, you can't enforce constraints like "a value should only appear in the list once" in SQL, if your list is just a comma-separated varchar field.

Comment: Or indeed constraints like "This field should contain numbers". Thanks for reminding me of that one

Answer (score 3):

Use a separate column for each value. See [`1NF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't ask "which is faster".
Speed is not the only thing to take into account. 
A space rocket is indeed faster than your family car, but you don't drive to the mall on a rocket.
So, you should ask "what way is proper one" instead.
And to normalize your database is the only proper way.

Comment: Agreed.  Get it right first, then make it faster *if you need to*.  But you won't know if you need to (or what to speed up, or whether your optimizations will make the solution wrong) til you have something that actually works.

Answer (score 0):

what about using something like:

```
int AutoId, // your primary key
int ColumnIndex // 1 for col 1
int ColumnValue // the value for e.g. for col 1

this does not need space for unused columns and gives the benefit to query like

select ColumIndex, ColumnValue where AutoID = 42 order by ColumnIndex
```

Comment: and yes, i assume string is slower as i believe fixed field length is always better. but if you dont deal with exabytes of data i assume you won't notice the small difference :-)